# Error on expandRangeByFactor method in Core Plot

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I'm having trouble getting a scatter plot to display. I'm using Core Plot 1.6 on Xcode 6.3 and following [this tutorial.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2)

I have followed the tutorial 'to a T' and the pie chart works but when moving to the scatter plot I get an error on lines like these...

```
[xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.1f)];
```

It says "Sending 'NSDecimal to a parameter of incompatible type 'NSNumber *'. So I instinctively change the line to this...

```
[xRange expandRangeByFactor:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.1f]];
```

And according to [this post by eskroch of Core Plot.](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/96)

> I pushed my Swift updates to the release-2.0 branch. I changed the type of all externally visible methods and properties from NSDecimal to NSNumber and/or supplemented them with equivalent ones with the new type. I updated all of the example apps to work with the new API and translated two of them (DatePlot and the iPhone version of CPTTestApp) to Swift. They compile, but I can't test them right now so please report any problems.

So I should be right in making it a NSNumber.

Then it compiles but the screen is blank. I have no idea what is going on... I assumed that the developer changed the CPTDecimalFromCGFloat method around or something but now I'm at a loss. **Does anyone have a quick thought of what it could be? Am I right in making this number a NSNumber rather than CPTDecimal?**

And below is the entire method where the problem is occurring.

```
-(void) configurePlots {
    // 1 - Get graph and plot space
    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    // 2 - Create the three plots
    CPTScatterPlot *aaplPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    aaplPlot.dataSource = self;
    aaplPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolAAPL;
    CPTColor *aaplColor = [CPTColor redColor];
    [graph addPlot:aaplPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    CPTScatterPlot *googPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    googPlot.dataSource = self;
    googPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolGOOG;
    CPTColor *googColor = [CPTColor greenColor];
    [graph addPlot:googPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    CPTScatterPlot *msftPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    msftPlot.dataSource = self;
    msftPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolMSFT;
    CPTColor *msftColor = [CPTColor blueColor];
    [graph addPlot:msftPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    // 3 - Set up plot space
    [plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:aaplPlot, googPlot, msftPlot, nil]];
    CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
    [xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.1f)]; // error here
    plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
    CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
    [yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.2f)]; // error here
    plotSpace.yRange = yRange;
    // 4 - Create styles and symbols
    CPTMutableLineStyle *aaplLineStyle = [aaplPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    aaplLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5;
    aaplLineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
    aaplPlot.dataLineStyle = aaplLineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *aaplSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    aaplSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
    CPTPlotSymbol *aaplSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    aaplSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:aaplColor];
    aaplSymbol.lineStyle = aaplSymbolLineStyle;
    aaplSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
    aaplPlot.plotSymbol = aaplSymbol;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *googLineStyle = [googPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    googLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;
    googLineStyle.lineColor = googColor;
    googPlot.dataLineStyle = googLineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *googSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    googSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = googColor;
    CPTPlotSymbol *googSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol starPlotSymbol];
    googSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:googColor];
    googSymbol.lineStyle = googSymbolLineStyle;
    googSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
    googPlot.plotSymbol = googSymbol;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *msftLineStyle = [msftPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    msftLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0;
    msftLineStyle.lineColor = msftColor;
    msftPlot.dataLineStyle = msftLineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *msftSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    msftSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = msftColor;
    CPTPlotSymbol *msftSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol diamondPlotSymbol];
    msftSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:msftColor];
    msftSymbol.lineStyle = msftSymbolLineStyle;
    msftSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
    msftPlot.plotSymbol = msftSymbol;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the 2.0 headers were included in the 1.6 package. I'll have to do a 1.6.1 release to fix it.